# IIS issue with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iis

I don't know if stack overflow is a right place to ask this question, but nevertheless.
I have a local site in ISS, it's called https://miami.com. I have 127.0.0.1 miami.com in my hosts file

Couple days ago in chrome, instead of opening my local site - another site site opening (https://www.miamiherald.com/). I have no idea why
In incognito mode everything works ok - my local site is showing.

please suggest, have no idea where to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved. DNS clear - doesn't help. Cache clear - doesn't help
Open Dev Tools and check off "Disable Cache"
[image]

Comment: "I have no idea why In incognito mode everything works ok - my local site is showing" is clearly the indicator that you hit a browser side cache issue, https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Comment: Disable Cache - this one helped me